# Concern about Yii2 Datetime formats Error

Tags: yii2

Hello i am trying to set my dateFormat to be php:l jS \of F Y but the system is not displaying as desired am expecting Monday 7th of September 2015 but it gives Monday 7 \2015

Comment: Can it be that your php is missing its `intl` extension?

Answer (score 0):

Formatter use this pattern syntax

http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2docs/yii-i18n-formatter.html#$dateFormat-detail

http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime#TOC-Date-Time-Format-Syntax

your format would something like:

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asDate(strtotime($model->attribute), $format = "EEEE dd 'of' LLLL yyyy KK:m:s a")
```

Don't know how to add the "st", "nd", "rd" part of your pattern. This is still missing from the pattern given above. (you can lookup yourself)

But you can also just use the normal php date function like:

```
echo date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A",strtotime($model->attribute));
```